# Need to adjust NSJSONSerialization to iOS10

Tags: swift, ios10

After upgrading to iOS10 users started complaining about crashes of my app.
I am testing it with iOS10 on the simulator and indeed the app crashes with a message saying "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' to 'NSMutableArray'". Here's my code, please help:

```
import Foundation

protocol getAllListsModel: class {
    func listsDownloadingComplete(downloadedLists: [ContactsList])
}

class ListsDownloader: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate{

    //properties

    weak var delegate: getAllListsModel!

    var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    func downloadLists() {

        let urlPath: String = "http://..."
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var session: NSURLSession!
        let configuration =     NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()     //defaultSessionConfiguration()


    session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url)

    task.resume()

}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    self.data.appendData(data);
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else {
        self.parseJSON()
        print("Lists downloaded")
    }

}
func parseJSON() {

    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    do{
        try jsonResult =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        }

        var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
        var downloadedLists: [ContactsList] = []

        for i in 0...jsonResult.count-1 {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let tempContactsList = ContactsList()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            let id = jsonElement["id"] as? String
            let name = jsonElement["name"] as? String
            let pin = jsonElement["pin"] as? String
            let lastUpdated = jsonElement["created"] as? String
            let listAdminDeviceID = jsonElement["admin"] as? String

            tempContactsList.id = id
            tempContactsList.name = name
            tempContactsList.pin = pin
            tempContactsList.lastUpdated = lastUpdated
            tempContactsList.listAdmin = listAdminDeviceID

            downloadedLists.append(tempContactsList)

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.listsDownloadingComplete(downloadedLists)

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Swift native collection types rather than unrelated type lacking (mutable) Foundation types, that solves your problems.

Comment: I have a similar issue in that my JSON parser is now producing NSDictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary. I need to continue to use mutable dictionaries, but I think the solution should be simple, in the sense that you could create a mutable copy: mutableDictionary = dictionary.mutableCopy(). I assume you could do something parallel for NSArray. I will let you know how I get on once I have chance to look at this in more detail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in iOS 9, there was no guarantee `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(_:options:)` would return mutable object or not. You should have specified `NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers`.

And in your code, you are not modifying `jsonResult`, which means you have no need to declare it as `NSMutableArray`. Just replace `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray`, and then you have no need to specify `NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers`.

But as vadian is suggesting, you better use Swift types rather than `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. This code should work both in iOS 9 and 10.

```
func parseJSON() {

    var jsonResult: [[String: AnyObject]] = [] //<- use Swift type

    do{
        try jsonResult =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options: []) as! [[String: AnyObject]] //<- convert to Swift type, no need to specify options

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    var downloadedLists: [ContactsList] = []

    for jsonElement in jsonResult { //<- your for-in usage can be simplified

        let tempContactsList = ContactsList()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        let id = jsonElement["id"] as? String
        let name = jsonElement["name"] as? String
        let pin = jsonElement["pin"] as? String
        let lastUpdated = jsonElement["created"] as? String
        let listAdminDeviceID = jsonElement["admin"] as? String

        tempContactsList.id = id
        tempContactsList.name = name
        tempContactsList.pin = pin
        tempContactsList.lastUpdated = lastUpdated
        tempContactsList.listAdmin = listAdminDeviceID

        downloadedLists.append(tempContactsList)

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.listsDownloadingComplete(downloadedLists)

    })
}
```

Try this and check it on iOS 10 devices.

(The `as!` conversion would cause some weird crashes when your server is malfunctioning, but that would be another issue, so I keep it there.)